# onclick of links created using a loop doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm pulling records from mysql database and i should implement paging. I already have display 50, 100, 300 records per page and can display the number of pages like
if there are 388 records, there would be 8 pages if 50 records is selected

Now I'm trying to make the paging links work using the onclick but to no avail

html

```
<table id="mainTable">
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>yuu</td>
    <td>KitsuneJima</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>shishio</td>
    <td>Yokohama</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>seijiro</td>
    <td>Hokaido</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>yumi</td>
    <td>Kawasaki</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>kaoru</td>
    <td>Shizuoka</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>sanosuke</td>
    <td>Aichi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>aomori</td>
    <td>Nagaishi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>seijiro</td>
    <td>Iwate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>seijiro</td>
    <td>Kyuushuu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>seijiro</td>
    <td>Honshuu</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>yahiko</td>
    <td>Honshuu</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
View Page&nbsp&nbsp<span id="mnPg"></span>&nbsp&nbsp<span id="tsugi">Next</span><br>

<select id="hyoujiKensuuSentakushi">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
function mainDraw(mnPge) {
var u=0;
var peji="";
zenpeji=10;
while(u<zenpeji)
{
  peji+='&nbsp<u id="hyoujiPeji'+(u+1)+'" onclick="$(function() {mainDraw('+(u+1)+')});">'+(u+1)+'</u>&nbsp';
  u++;
}
}
});
$('#mnPg').html(peji);
```

css

```
u
{
cursor: pointer
}
```

I tried passing a value to the function but I wonder why i doesnt work

Comment: If you're using jquery, why would you make a hard to read inline javascript call like that? Not to mention `u` is deprecated and should be replaced with CSS `text-decoration:underline`.

Comment: Oh and "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Are there errors? Can you make a fiddle? Thingz we need to know!

Comment: i dont get what are you trying to pass ?

Comment: wherever you learned this stuff must have been very outdated...learning wrong things is worse than learning nothing. But don't worry i'll help you :D

Comment: I too would like to be updated but for the meantime if this stuff will work, and then I would not hesitate to use this, saves time XD i'm creating a pagination for records showed on a table please please treat the one on jsfiddle as something pulled on mysql now, the pages link that are created by loop varies with the total number of records and the number of records to display per page so my idea is setting the mnPge equal to the page value example if 5 then mnPge=5. the links should not necessarily be link, coz like the next page button I created, its fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was fiddling when you commented your question.
Here, try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hige/hR3YF/

You seem to have an issue with scopes. The function mainDraw was not attached to "window" therefore, not being reachable.

Regards

/*Old reply

I noticed a couple of things wrong with the code.
First, you pass the mnPge parameter, but never use it.
Second, the scope of the var "peji". If you want `$('#mnPg').html(peji);` to work, you should either define peji globally or include that line within the scope of mainDraw().

Also, as the guys said, you may want to be clearer. What do you want to do, what errors or issues you ar having, etc. so we can help you.

Anyway, I tried somethin that may help, but it makes no sense because you are drawing links to the same function that drew them, but here you have, I hope it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/hige/eGCg4/
*/

Comment: Oh sorry if I sound vague, i'm creating a pagination for records showed on a table, pulled on an mysql database, so please assume the one I created on jsfiddle as sample data, now, the pages that are created by loop varies with the total number of records and the number of records to display per page so I would like the links 1 2 3 4 etc... to function, my idea is setting the mnPge equal to the page value example if 5 then mnPge=5

Comment: I added a new version in my answer, and is working for me.
Please check it and let mw know if it work.

Comment: where it is located sir? maybe you forgot to give the link

Comment: doumo! I added something to the code inside the loop, in jsfiddle its ok but in local it doesnt work and the odd-color of table suddenly didnt appear, what else I could check? any suggestions please

Comment: Would you have a fiddle with that?

Comment: Already solved it, I updated jquery and it worked fine thanks